# google-drive 'Binary' attribute getting set on text files. google-drive-ocamlfuse todo.txt-cli

Tags: text, binary, google-drive-api, file-type

todo.txt-cli is a CLI ToDo List App. It saves it's data in text files.
google-drive-ocamlfuse is a FUSE filesystem for Google Drive.
I have todo.txt-cli directed to save it's text data files to my google-drive mount-point.
I also use ToDo.txt Android App directed to use the same google-drive folder.
Each works fine on it's own.
Problem is when the linux todo.txt-cli makes a change, the todo.txt file in Google-Drive gets changed to a file-type of Binary.  Once it's a binary file, the Android App can no longer see the file.

Researching this I found someone experiencing the same problem with files edited by Libre Office. One response suggested the problem is related to Libre Office use of .tmp files while editing.
I expect use of .tmp is pretty common across all apps.  Why would Google API set file-type of binary based solely on an extension of .tmp?